# How to avoid processing events multiple times due to horizontal scaling?

Tags: events, redis, spring-data-redis

I have a publish/subscriber setup where one application sends an event an one application receives it.

I'm implementing it by using the redis pub/subscribe so:

```
RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
container.addMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener), "topic1");
```

It works fine but now I have a problem: on my production setup I have a replication of nodes, so what happens is that an event is fired twice and the subscriber repeats twice the same code.

Isn't there any way, such for example an hash, to prevent redis to publish an event that has already been sent?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use Redis pub/sub in year 2020 now. The single biggest drawback of it is that it doesn't persist messages. E.g., you consummer service disconnects due to some network issue. The publisher publishes a message, then your consumer reconnects, it will not receive the message. It's lost.

Instead, use **Redis Stream** introcdued in Redis 5.0. The consumer group is what you're looking for.

> Consumer groups were initially introduced by the popular messaging system called Kafka (TM). Redis reimplements a similar idea in completely different terms, but the goal is the same: to allow a group of clients to cooperate consuming a different portion of the same stream of messages.

However, for a quick and dirty fix of your current issue.
Your publisher wants to publish a message, saying cusomter 123 paid the orderId 1111. Now you generate a random numer, for example, 27656.
It publishes to channel X the message     27656:123:1111

Your consumers subscribe to channel X, it parses the message, got the message number 27656, setnx String 27656 for a timeout period of one minute, if it succeeds, you know the the message 27656 is the first time being consumed and goes on to consume the message body 123:1111 . Otherwise, just silently discard this message.

Comment: Do streams also allow me to listen to streams not yet created? Or do I need to create a stream beforehand? Also, can I create a consumer group on application startup and if it already exists, connect to it?

Comment: Yes, yes. Both can be accomplished